# Sitecore Sortorder vs Subitem Sorting

Tags: sorting, sitecore, subitem

In Sitecore, I thought that sortorder always took precedence over subitem sorting. I was under the assumption that it doesn't matter what an item's subitem sorting was set to if one of it's children had a sortorder of 100 and the other had one of 0 the one with 0 would show up first. On a recent project I'm seeing the opposite happen in the content tree. Subitem sorting is being given the priority. Is there a way to configure the order in which sortorder and subitem sorting is checked? I've been looking around my web.config and diffed it with one I had for a project that was working the way I thought it should but I couldn't find anything that jumped out to me.

Visual of what I'm seeing in the content tree for the project that seems to give subitem sorting priority:

```
parent - subitem sorting = created
   child1 - created = 01012014, sortorder = 100
   child2 - created = 02022014, sortorder = 0
```

Comment: Where are you looking it? Is it in the Sitecore tree where the sortorder is not being respected?

Comment: Yes in the content editor items are showing up in a way I wouldn't expect. I haven't tried to pull the items out through the parent item's Children property but it's probably a good idea to try that and see what order they come out in.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a bug in Sitecore but it also may be working as intended, you may have to contact Sitecore support to find out which.

The Child Sorting for "Created" points to Sitecore.Data.Comparers.CreatedComparer,Sitecore.Kernel.  If you look at the ExtractKey() method in this class you will see that it does not include the original item's SortOrder.  Without out this Sitecore will only sort on Created Date.

```
   public override IKey ExtractKey(Item item)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        KeyObj keyObj = new KeyObj()
        {
            Item = item,
            Key = this.GetCreationDate(item)
        };
        return keyObj;
    }
```

In contrast you can look at the Child Sorting for "Updated" which points to Sitecore.Data.Comparers.UpdatedComparer,Sitecore.Kernel.  In its ExtractKey() method you see it is returning the item's Sort order so you will get a blended sort between Updated Date and Sort Order.

```
public override IKey ExtractKey(Item item)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        KeyObj keyObj = new KeyObj()
        {
            Item = item,
            Key = item.Statistics.Updated,
            Sortorder = item.Appearance.Sortorder
        };
        return keyObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a custom sorter to be used, it's entirely up to the code that runs the comparer on how items are sorted.

The comparer must be a `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`, but after that there's no guarantee on whether the sort order field will be used, or that if it is used it will be in an ascending or descending order.

I recommend examining the sorter that is selected for the particular item, and using dotPeek to analyze the source code for the sorter.

---

When building customized sorters, it's good practice to extend Sitecore's `Sitecore.Data.Comparers.Comparer` class and override the `DoCompare` method. It will consistently handle the sort order field, and fall back to the `DoCompare` method for secondary sorting.